# How to apply tab to indented space with document format (ctrl + K + D)?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013

I recently switched from Visual Studio 2012 Premium to **Visual Studio 2013** Premium and am having an issue with applying tabs instead of whitespace.

This is for **JavaScript**.
I had it working just fine on VS2012 but not VS2013 even I believe I set same formatting options.

Below is the issue:
As you can see, lots of white space being added for indentation part each line.
**My goal is to replace it with tab**.

[image]

My Setting:
[image]

Also when I Ctrl+K+D which should format entire document, it applies whitespace instead of tab for indented parts.

What am I missing here? What options do I need to set so that **Ctrl+K+D applies tabs not whitespace?**

It should look like below:
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Firstly press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>R</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> short keys, you will see some blue dots in the text representing spaces, after that from the Visual Studio menu, select `Tools > Options`
In the dialogue just opened, follow this path:
`Text Editor > All Languages > Tabs` check `Keep Tabs` radio button, you might need to restart Visual Studio, now open your file in Visual Studio and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>K</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> again, if every thing is OK you will see blue arrow key instead of those blue dots implying tab replaced with space.

You can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>R</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> short keys again to dismiss those arrow keys.

Answer (score 1):

After the same setting mentioned in the post, I restarted VS2013 and now Ctrl + K, Ctrl + D works with tabs.

So answer is, if options configured are not being applied, try restart VS2013.